# Clojure : treverse through json and return true or false, depending on the contion check result for each key:value pair in given document

Tags: json, clojure, jsonparser

I have tried to return true or false depending on the value present in the given hash-map. I have tried using reduced-kv but it really doesn't work.

for eg :
`{:address {:zip 411045, :city "pune"}, :coupans ["abc" "def"], :cost 200, :items [{:category "partywear", :name "shirt", :price 50.26} {:category "partywear", :name "trouser", :price 10.26}]}`

I want to write a function such that if `"items.price" = 50.26
and "items.name" = "shirt"`,, should return true but `"items.price = 10.26 and "items.name" = "shirt"` should return false .

I am first flattening the array and then changing the key to regex key 
`(def compare_str_regex (clojure.string/replace compare_str #"\[\]" "\\\\[\\[0-9\\]+\\\\]"))`
for eg : items[].price  -- > items[[0-9]+].price
Then I use reduce-kv to iterate, but the problem is it will check all the doc 
it should use the and condition between the two key sent

```
(reduce-kv (fn [m k v]
             (if (and (re-find (re-pattern compare_str_regex ) k)
                      (op value v))
               (reduced true)
               false))  {} flat_pl_map)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and include what you've tried. Thanks.

Comment: @BobJarvis I did thanks !

Comment: You may want to do a bit of reading to help you understand how to approach problems like this:   https://www.braveclojure.com/clojure-for-the-brave-and-true/

Comment: @AlanThompson thanks Alan, but I did some work on it too. I am working on it since few days, but not able to find exact solution, thus posted here !

Comment: You should have a look at the standard function `get-in`, which gets you at least part of the way to what you want. For example, if your JSON structure above is defined as `json-data` you could find the price of the first item using `(get-in json-data [:items 0 :price])`. You'd need to enhance it to walk through any embedded collections, such as `:items`, and then come up with a way to handle testing the results and handling the `and` condition.

Answer (score 1):

If the rule is "return true if there are *any* entries in the `items`
collection with `:name` `"shirt"` and `:price` `50.26`", then I would write that function like this:

If that's correct, then I would write that function like this:

```
(fn [{:keys [items]}]
  (some (fn [{:keys [name price]}]
          (and (= "shirt" name) (= 50.26 price)))
        items))
```

Comment: hey thanks for the reply. Actually what the problem statement is, There can be multiple keys like items.name "shirt", items.price "10.00".. I want to check if both the key value pairs are satisfied in same payload inside array of Items